# How to properly stop and start bot in pyrogram(not restart)

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I want clients to be able to stop a bot, and after a while start it again. If I use stop() function, and then start() function again, it no longer receives any updates. I don't want to use restart(), because restart starts straight away, which is not what I want? How can you suggest I fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you want to implement a `pause()` and `unpause()` instead of starting and stopping the program.

Comment: yeah, exactly, so the question is, is it already implemented and I don't see it?